# Conditional parameter to fetch records using query in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using `SQL Server 2008 R2`.

I do have a `stored procedure` in which I am passing `two parameters` - `Month` and `Year`. By `default` both are `NULL`.

The logic is if `Month` and `Year` are `NULL` then fetch the previous month's records from the table. For example, today is March 5, 2014, if Month and Year are passed as `NULL` then stored procedure will return records of previous Month i.e. February 1st, 2014 to February 28, 2014.

And if I pass `specific` `Month` and `Year` then it will fetch records of that Month and Year from the table.

The stored procedure is as below :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Proc_SalesRecords] (@Month INT = NULL, @year INT = NULL)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @dtnow DATETIME = GETDATE()

    IF @Month IS NULL
        SELECT @Month = MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, @dtnow ))

    IF @Year IS NULL
        SELECT @year = YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, @dtnow ))

    SELECT * FROM SalesRecords
    WHERE 
        ISNULL(@Month, MONTH(CreatedDate)) = MONTH(CreatedDate) 
        AND ISNULL(@year, YEAR(CreatedDate)) = YEAR(CreatedDate)  
        AND IsDeleted=0 

END     
GO
```

Now, I got new requirement to pass a new parameter `Day` to the same procedure i.e. `@Day INT = NULL`.

If `Day` is set to `NULL` then procedure should run as it is. But if `@Day` is `not null` then I need to fetch records for that day of the month in the `previous` month to `one day less` in `this month`.

For example if `@Day = 22, @Month = null, @year = null`, (and today is March 22th, 2014) it would fetch data for `February 22nd - March 21st 2014`.

Please let me now what changes should I do for this optional parameter in above given stored procedure and set the date range according to it?

Thanks

Comment: Not answer but doubt; is below line correct? Why select previous year?

Comment: Not the previous year but previous month. According to the stored procedure if month and year are passed then it will fetch records of that specific month and year, but if not then for year also I am just subtracting month from the current date that if current month is January,2014 then records should be fetched for previous month that is December, 2013.

Comment: Any SQL Experts available?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Conditional WHERE clause for fetching records](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22216066/conditional-where-clause-for-fetching-records)

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

Declare @Day int = 22

Declare @lastMonthDate dateTime, @FromDate datetime, @ToDate datetime

Set @lastMonthDate=dateadd (M, -1, GETDATE());

Set @FromDate=Convert(date, convert(varchar,Year(@lastMonthDate)) + '-' +  convert(varchar,MONTH(@lastMonthDate)) + '-' + convert(varchar, @Day) )
set @ToDate = Dateadd(M,1,@FromDate)-1

select @FromDate, @Todate

Answer (score 0):

May this help

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Proc_SalesRecords] (@Day INT = NULL, @Month INT = NULL, @year INT = NULL)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @dtnow DATETIME = GETDATE()

    IF @Month IS NULL
        SELECT @Month = MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, @dtnow ))

    IF @Year IS NULL
        SELECT @year = YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, @dtnow ))

    SELECT * FROM SalesRecords
    WHERE 
        ISNULL(@Month, MONTH(CreatedDate)) = MONTH(CreatedDate) 
        AND ISNULL(@year, YEAR(CreatedDate)) = YEAR(CreatedDate)  
        AND ((DAY(CreatedDate) BETWEEN ISNULL(@Day, DAY(CreatedDate)) AND DAY(DATEADD(DAY,-1,@dtnow))) OR (@Day IS NULL))
        AND IsDeleted=0 


END     
GO
```