# Conditional WHERE clause for fetching records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

I am having an SQL block as below :

```
DECLARE @Day INT = 5
DECLARE @Month INT = NULL
DECLARE @year INT = NULL
DECLARE @dtnow DATETIME

SET @dtnow = GETDATE()

IF @Month IS NULL
    SELECT @Month = MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH,-1, @dtnow ))

IF @Year IS NULL
    SELECT @year = YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH,-1, @dtnow ))


SELECT * 
FROM TblSalesRecords 
WHERE 
    CASE WHEN @Day IS NULL THEN -- Condition One
        BEGIN 
            ISNULL(@Month, MONTH(TblSalesRecords.CreatedDate)) = MONTH(TblSalesRecords.CreatedDate) 
            AND (@year, YEAR(TblSalesRecords.CreatedDate)) = YEAR(TblSalesRecords.CreatedDate)
        END 
    ELSE                        -- Condition two
        BEGIN 
            TblSalesRecords.CreatedDate BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR,YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH,-1, @dtnow ))) + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,month(DATEADD(MONTH,-1,@dtnow))) + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DAY(DATEADD(MONTH,-1,@dtnow))) +' 00:00:00.000') 
            AND CONVERT (DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR,YEAR(DATEADD(DAY,-1,@dtnow ))) + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,MONTH(DATEADD(DAY,-1,@dtnow))) + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DAY(DATEADD(DAY,-1,@dtnow))) +' 23:59:59.998')
        END
    END 
    AND TblSalesRecords.IsDeleted=0
```

What I want to achieve is,

If `@Day` is set to `NULL` then it should execute the `CASE..WHEN` Statement of *-- Condition One* else of *-- Condition two*.

But I am getting Syntax error near `"="` in `CASE..WHEN` Statement.

Can anyone let me know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it this way:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TblSalesRecords 
WHERE (@Day IS NULL 
            AND ISNULL(@Month, MONTH(TblSalesRecords.CreatedDate)) = MONTH(TblSalesRecords.CreatedDate) 
            AND (@year, YEAR(TblSalesRecords.CreatedDate)) = YEAR(TblSalesRecords.CreatedDate)
       )
    OR (@Day IS NOT NULL                      -- Condition two
            AND TblSalesRecords.CreatedDate BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR,YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH,-1, @dtnow ))) + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,month(DATEADD(MONTH,-1,@dtnow))) + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DAY(DATEADD(MONTH,-1,@dtnow))) +' 00:00:00.000') 
            AND CONVERT (DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR,YEAR(DATEADD(DAY,-1,@dtnow ))) + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,MONTH(DATEADD(DAY,-1,@dtnow))) + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DAY(DATEADD(DAY,-1,@dtnow))) +' 23:59:59.998')
        )
    AND TblSalesRecords.IsDeleted=0
```

There's another syntax error in `(@year, YEAR(TblSalesRecords.CreatedDate)) = YEAR(TblSalesRecords.CreatedDate)` but I'm not sure what should be there so I left it as it is.

Comment: Thanks Syzmon. Let me check it.

Comment: Not working. In this case condition 1 and condition two both of them are fetching records.

Comment: Is @Day null or not in this case? It's hard to give you a definite answer without seeing data.

Comment: Day is set to null. DECLARE @Day INT = NULL.

Comment: The exact case is, when I set Day as NULL then I will fetch all the records of previous month. That's why I have set SELECT Month = MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH,-1, dtnow )) where "dtnow" is current date. And if Day is not null then I want to fetch the records starting from previous month's day what I have passed as Day to one day less than the day of this month.

Comment: Thanks it worked for me after solving the logical error in BEGIN END Block of Day = NULL